# Pagination for normal (standard) posts on a page with a custom loop?

Tags: posts, loop, pages, pagination

probably a rather straight forward question.

my "homepage" is not the blog-page. I have a `page-template` named `page-knowledge.php` which has the following loop on it.

```
<?php
        echo '<ul class="blog-items">';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            global $post;
            get_template_part( 'inc/post', 'item' );
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

So, this page queries `5` of the normal posts. How can I add a pagination to this page so I can jump through the rest of the posts just like you would expect it.

---

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
        echo '<ul class="blog-items">';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            global $post;
            get_template_part( 'inc/post', 'item' );
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</ul>';
    ?>

    <div class="pagination wrapper">
        <?php 
            $endsize = $midsize = 1;
            $type = 'plain';
            $loop->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $loop->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

            // Sanitize input argument values
            if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'plain', 'list', 'array' ) ) ) $type = 'plain';
            $endsize = (int) $endsize;
            $midsize = (int) $midsize;

            // Setup argument array for paginate_links()
            $pagination = array(
                'base'          => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
                'total'         => $loop->max_num_pages,
                'current'       => $current,
                'show_all'      => false,
                'end_size'      => $endsize,
                'mid_size'      => $midsize,
                'type'          => $type,
                'prev_next'     => false,
                'paged'         => $loop->query_vars['paged']
            );

            echo paginate_links( $pagination );
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_pagination_links` is looking at `$wp_query`, whereas you want pagination for your query object named `$loop`.  So instead, use `paginate_links`

Something similar to this code, which is based on `get_pagination_links`, alebit with wp-query swapped out for your loop query object:

```
$endsize = $midsize = 1;
$type = 'plain';
$loop->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $loop->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

// Sanitize input argument values
if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'plain', 'list', 'array' ) ) ) $type = 'plain';
$endsize = (int) $endsize;
$midsize = (int) $midsize;

// Setup argument array for paginate_links()
$pagination = array(
    'base'          => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
    'total'         => $loop->max_num_pages,
    'current'       => $current,
    'show_all'      => false,
    'end_size'      => $endsize,
    'mid_size'      => $midsize,
    'type'          => $type,
    'prev_next'     => false,
    'paged'         => $loop->query_vars['paged']
);

echo paginate_links( $pagination );
```

Finally you'll need to grab the `paged` URL variable via $_GET, do a tad sanitisation ( check it's a number and it's set ), then put it into your `WP_Query` args array